# How can i convert format cells of csv file using notepad?

Tags: excel

i am trying to create file of csv extension but i want to format it with with notepad the problem is a column includes phone numbers and the numbers start with 010******* and when i try to open it in excel it consider the column is a number value so it removes the 0 (10*******) i want to format the cell as a string value.

i tried adding "01********" but the same problem happened.

the code is :

email,phone

example@company.com,01123456789

example2@company.com,0121223456789

Comment: Try putting a single `'` in front of the phone number

Comment: There are no cells or formats in csv files, they are just plain text. Excel adds formating to imported text using some guessing algorithms. A good solution for you might be to open csv files not directly, but via Power Query in Excel. There, you have full control of the format. Go to tab "Data", then "New Query", then "From File", select "CSV file", and proceed from there.

Comment: Usually much better to **Import** a csv file, NOT **Open**.  If you **Import** you will be given the opportunity to format a column as text.